# How to convert videos in nodejs without ffmpeg?

Tags: node.js, converters

I want to convert couple pieces of video to another format. How can I do that without already installed ffmpeg on server (in my case its impossible to install it)?

Answer (score 1):

You would have to re-implement the majority of ffmpeg's functionality in JavaScript which is more than likely not feasible.  ffmpeg is a well established project with countless hours invested in it's development.